# Is the expression of elastic energy in this paper correct?

Tags: energy, symmetry, crystals, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

[Elastic properties of Ni2MnGa from first-principles calculations](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jallcom.2010.08.039)

I am reading a paper investigating the linear elasticity of a crystal. However, I am a little bit confused over the expression of energy over strain of a cubic crystal:

[image]

These are expressed over Voigt notation.
Shouldn't the last equation be
$\Delta E/V_0 = 0.5C_{44} \delta ^2$ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please specify the paper. I'll never understand why people ask for help regarding some puzzling result online or in the literature but never give the context-providing source. Here, we might expect apparent factor-of-four discrepancies to arise from the engineering shear strain being twice the tensorial shear strain, but let's see what the authors are talking about first.